# PHP OOP, undefined property. How can I get this to work?

Tags: php, oop

Okay so I'm basically trying to improve with PHP OOP, however I'm not too sure how I should do this. Could someone please point out the issue?

The code returns the following errors:

Notice: Undefined property: registration::$userExist
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object

The class:

```
class registration extends connect{

        public function userExist(){
            global $dsn;

        $userExist = $this->dsn->prepare("
            SELECT * FROM accounts
            WHERE username= :username
            ");

$userExist->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $userExist->execute();

        $rows = $this->userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            return $rows;
        }
```

How I'm trying to use the class on a page:

```
$conn = new connect();
$registration  = new registration();

$rows = $registration->userExist();
                    if($rows < 1){
// do something
```

Comment: You don't have to use `$this` on a global variable.

Comment: Yeah, but do you know the reason It isn't working?

Comment: I can guess. Not enough information to see though. When the prepare failed it will not return an object. So your `$userExist` will not be an object. When it is not an object id doesn't have any property. In this case the `fetch`.

Comment: I just wanted to add that because you're using OOP syntax doesn't mean it's Object Oriented code. Take the normal example. `duck extends animal`, while `registration extends connect` doesn't make sense. Registration is not a type of `connect`/(connection).  What you need is instead of using  `global` use dependency injection. Pass the `connect` to `registration` via the `registration`'s constructor. More on that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Comment: Can you tell me what is in `$dsn` and how you initialized it? Was it in the connect class ? And `$dsn` defined there in the constructor of connect class? Was it declared to be protected var ?

Comment: connect is just a class to keep my pdo connection and dsn is the PDO connection, dsn is a protected var and is in the constructor.

Comment: Your `$username` where does it come from ?

Comment: $username comes from a POST variable

Comment: But you used it in a function scope. It can't get the value from outside it's class unless you inject it.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? this could be the reason it isn't working

Comment: You better read this [http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_variables.asp] about variable scope. For this case you can define `$username = $_POST['username']` before you use it or pass it to the function as a parameter.

Comment: But isn't myTest(); in that example just the same as using $registration  = new registration();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that it cannit find variable $userExist, this is because on the last line you are looking for variable "$userExist" inside "$this" while you defined it as a normal variables a few lines above it.

To fix the problem, drop the `this->` part of the line that gives the error so it pick up the variable from the local scope

```
$rows = $userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

**EDIT**
You said in comments that variable $username was properly defined before you called the method `userExists()`. However, in php variables won't be copied over to inside of the function code block when they are called. To pass variables you need to add an argument to the function.

```
public function userExist($username){
        ...
        $rows = $userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        ....
    }
```

And you need to use it like:

```
....
$rows = $registration->userExist($username);
....
```

Comment: Now I get Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'username' cannot be null'

Comment: Are you sure $username is defined when your function is called, can you do `var_dump($username)` to see if its correctly populated?

Comment: I added the var dump above the $rows = $registration->userExist(); and it displays string "Bob"

Comment: You said you listed it before you called userExists(). In php, variables wont be moved over into functions if defined outside of the. In other words, the variable in normal "Bob" outside of your function, but is undefined inside the function block. Working on an edit of my answer now...

Comment: Ah I was thinking about putting variables into the () of the function but I just wasn't sure how it exactly worked, thanks for explaining it. Your solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you don't have a property `userExist` in the class `registration`.

Just change

```
$rows = $this->userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

for

```
$rows = $userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need $this->userExist

```
class registration extends connect{
  public function userExist(){
        global $dsn;
        $this->dsn = $dsn; // assign global $dsn to $this->dsn
        $userExist = $this->dsn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE `username`= :username");
        $userExist->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $userExist->execute();
        $rows = $userExist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
            return $rows;
        }
```